# Java Support in Visual Studio Code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

When I hover over highlighted errors and wait for a suggestion, the tooltip freezes with a "Loading" message (see attached image). Below are some messages from the Java Console when I start the project in code:

```
[Info  - 6:04:59 PM] Connection closed
[Warn  - 6:04:59 PM] Unexpected params 'java.lang.Void@762ca2b4' for 'public default void org.eclipse.lsp4j.services.LanguageServer.initialized()' is ignored
[Warn  - 6:04:59 PM] Unsupported notification method: $/setTraceNotification
[Info  - 6:04:59 PM] Lint file:///Users/m/git/******/src/main/java/***/*****/******/dbpojo/Test.java
[Info  - 6:04:59 PM] Emit effective pom for /Users/m/git/moppet/pom.xml to /var/folders/16/jklb51p1409_wpyx8t78y8bm0000gn/T/effective-pom2290539182353371595.xml
[Info  - 6:05:08 PM] Emit classpath to /var/folders/16/jklb51p1409_wpyx8t78y8bm0000gn/T/classpath2404906236906906885.txt
```

Here's some information about my configuration:

- Mac OS Sierra 10.12.5
- Java 1.8.0_131
- I also have "Language Support for Java by Red Hat" installed, but it seems to be the same result without it.
- Maven 4.0.0

[image: Loading on the error suggestion tooltip image]

Comment: This is because Visual Studio Code doesn't know how to handle the Java documentation.  Your using an editor that has virtually no support for Java.

Comment: Haha. Well. Nothing I can do about that then. But the documentation for the java plugin promised suggestions. :(

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio Code is a code editor rather than a full-fledged Integrated Development Environment (IDE). For a better Java development experience, you might want to use an IDE such as [IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/).

## VS Code Java Extension Pack

Having said that, Visual Studio Code can be an excellent editor for Java development with the help of a few extensions. Install the [Java Extension Pack](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/java) and you should have built in code completion, debugging and Maven support.

[image: Java extension]

Note that for the Java extensions to work properly, you need to either set `java.home` within Visual Studio Code, or the `JDK_HOME` and `JAVA_HOME` environment variables.

[image: Java debugging]

Comment: The Java Extension Pack relies on the Language Support for Java by Red Hat extension for parsing and compiler support ... which the question mentions is already installed. That said, they might have forgotten to specify the jdk path.